# Changing the value of a cell based on the first digit

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Ok, trying and struggling to do it
I am not a pro in excel but try to do something so I can keep track of something.

Cell A1 have a value of 4225566558
Cell A2 have a value of 2225584545

What I need is - If in column A the first digit /s is 4 or 04 I would need the output in Column B to be 0.055 otherwise it will be 0.044

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A1,1) = "4", LEFT(A1, 2) = "04"), 0.055, 0.044)
```

`LEFT(A1,1)` checks the first value and `LEFT(A1, 2)` checks the first two values.

Just drag the cell (B1) from the bottom right corner to copy the function for additional cells.